# Target last div in the group

Tags: html, css, siblings

I need to target each last `<div>` before each `<h3>`. Is there a programatic way this can be done in css?

For other reasons, I can not /  don't want to target `<h3>` instead.

```
<div id="main">

    <h3>Title</h3>
    <div class="post">…</div>
    <div class="post"><!-- Target this div--></div>

    <h3>Title</h3>
    <div class="post">…</div>
    <div class="post">…</div>
    <div class="post">…</div>
    <div class="post"><!-- Target this div--></div>

    <h3>Title</h3>
    <div class="post">…</div>
    <div class="post">…</div>
    <div class="post"><!-- Target this div--></div>

</div>
```

Comment: What's the criteria for selecting that last div that doesn't have an h3 after it?

Comment: I'm afraid there's no prior sibling selection in CSS3. You can still do it with Js tough.

Comment: Without changing your markup somehow, you can't do this with CSS. If you put each section inside of its own <section> element, then it would be easy to use the `last-child` pseudo-selector that Lal mentioned.

Comment: @j08691 Each .post will have a border-bottom and margin-bottom. I don't want the last .post just before the <h3> to have these styles because it will look awkward.

Comment: I realize I could implement border-top and margin-top instead, but  then I'd be rewriting rules since all my styles follow a certain, consistent pattern of applying margin and border to the bottom of elements.

Comment: Would you be so kind and let us know whether you found another solution (and answer your question on your own in this case - so we can also benefit from your investigations) or one of the given answers fitted your needs (and mark the adäquate answer as accepted in this case to honor the communities efforts)? :)

Answer (score 2):

### Actually this isn't possible.

If you are able to **wrap the blocks into parent tags** you can get each last child by CSS selectors `#main .post:last-child`:

```
<div id="main">

  <div>               <!-- wrap with "h3" WORKS -->
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <div class="post">…</div>
    <div class="post"><!-- Target this div--></div>
  </div>

  <h3>Title</h3>
  <div>               <!-- wrap without "h3" also WORKS -->
    <div class="post">…</div>
    <div class="post">…</div>
    <div class="post"><!-- Target this div--></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Note: The :last-child selector is not supported in IE8 and earlier versions.

---

What do you mean with: "For other reasons, I can not / don't want to target  instead."?

---

**jQuery** workaround will work exactly like you want it **with your original markup:**

```
var $Main = jQuery('#main');
$Main.find('h3').prev().add( $Main.find(':last') )    //.text('<!-- Target this div-->');
```

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback. I thought it wouldn't be possible either. I wanted to avoid wrapping each group inside another div, but that seems more realistic. Also, `jQuery('h3').prev()` seems great if there won't be too many <h3> selectors.

Comment: If you are'nt able to handle your situation propperly just post all your circumstances.
For example if you are generating your code with php you could probably even handle it just while generating your markup.
Maybe you need just an inspiration for a propper workaround...

Comment: The jQuery solution will miss the last element.

Answer (score 1):

At some point in the future, when [selectors level 4](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/) are implemented:

```
#main div:not(:has(+ div))
```

Comment: I just found an article on [css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/) I saw awhile ago which lead me to believe parent selectors might be part of css3. Also, saw [cssParentSelector](https://github.com/Idered/cssParentSelector), perhaps if used as a polyfill, but overkill for just one instance.

Comment: No, there are no parent selectors in CSS3. Sure, use that polyfill if you want, personally I would not use a jQuery plugin.